# Is it possible to define a property like strain to characterize the structural change?

Tags: condensed-matter, stress-strain

Lets suppose that I have an atom chain like system 1 below. Now, some interaction made one atom to move out of the chain, like shown in system 2 (the moved atom remains bounded but in another position). This change is permanent.

Knowing all the coordinates for all the atoms: **Is it possible to define a property like strain to characterize the structural change?**
(I'm not sure if the RMSD could be a good parameter to use here)

```
System 1: ************


               *          
System 2: ***** ******
```

Answer (score 2):

I would select a group of atoms and calculate the relative deviation along the 3 dimensions. So I would take the initial (x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>, z<sub>i</sub>) and final (x<sub>f</sub>, y<sub>f</sub>, z<sub>f</sub>) coordinates and then calculate the 3N-dimensional distance using

$$\sqrt{(x_f-x_i)^2 + (y_f-y_i)^2 + (z_f-z_i)^2}$$

Those atoms there were not affected will have values zero, and values other than zero would reflect the extent change.

Comment: Assuming there is no uniform translation ... Depending on the method used you might have to correct for that. Similarly for rotations.